# React Router v4 not rendering parent components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, nested, react-router, react-router-dom

I have my routes set up as following (index.js):

```
<BrowserRouter history={browserHistory}>
   <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={RootContainer} />
      <Route exact path="/login" component={RedirectToApp(LoginPage)} />
      <Route exact path="/dashboard" component={RequiresAuth(AppContainer)} />
      <Route exact path="/dashboard/venues" component={VenuesPage} />
   </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

In my AppContainer I have my component written as:

```
render() {
    return (
      <div className='wrapper main-app-wrapper'>
        <Header toggleSidebar={this.toggleSidebar}>
          <AuthHeaderActions />
        </Header>
         <div className='content-wrapper'>
          {this.props.children}
        </div>
        <LeftMenu />
        <Footer />
      </div>
    );
  }
```

When I go to the route /dashboard, the header, footer and the left menu get rendered properly.

But when I hit the route /dashboard/venues, only the content present inside the VenuesPage is rendered. The header, footer and leftmenu are not getting rendered. Having a problem with nesting of routes. I am using react-router-dom - v4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `Routes` within your components with `react-router v4`

You can change the routes to

**index.js**

```
<BrowserRouter history={browserHistory}>
   <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={RootContainer} />
      <Route exact path="/login" component={RedirectToApp(LoginPage)} />
      <Route path="/dashboard" component={RequiresAuth(AppContainer)} />

   </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Now that you want the `VenuesPage` to be child of the `AppContainer`. You can add it within the `AppContainer` component like

```
render() {
    return (
      <div className='wrapper main-app-wrapper'>
        <Header toggleSidebar={this.toggleSidebar}>
          <AuthHeaderActions />
        </Header>
         <div className='content-wrapper'>
          {this.props.children}
          <Route exact path="/dashboard/venues" component={VenuesPage} />
        </div>
        <LeftMenu />
        <Footer />
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: Doing this takes me to an empty page when I hit the route /dashboard/venues. Basically, this route is not found. I am new to v4 so a bit confused here.

Comment: Are you sure you removed the exact attribute from /dashboard route

Answer (score 2):

You need to put the *venues* Route inside *dashboard*

```
<Route exact path="/dashboard" component={RequiresAuth(AppContainer)}>
    <Route exact path="/venues" component={VenuesPage}/>
</Route>
```

EDIT

NB! As the comments (and the other answer) state, this is no longer valid for V4.

Comment: Already tried this. Doing this gives this error:  Warning: You should not use <Route component> and <Route children> in the same route; <Route children> will be ignored. The child route is not working here.

Comment: Not quite true for react-router v4. However it will work with v3 or earlier